# Enterprise Library DAAB for JAVA?

Tags: java, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

I'm looking for a java library thats similar to .NET's Enterprise Library specifically the Data Access block.

More details.. working on a java poc and would like a library to build the data access.. no ORM's or something too complicated. The library should be able to use MsSQL as a database.

Comment: Hibernate and DAAB are very similar, is there a reason you wouldnt consider Hibernate? It can connect to MS SQL.

Comment: Hibernate (which I have not used) is an ORM.. DAAB is a wrapper library.. so I'm not sure they are similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the [Spring Framework's JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/jdbc.html) might be what you're looking for.  It's a helper class for Java's built-in database library, JDBC.  It wraps and simplifies JDBC calls, and allows you to pretty easily map rows to objects.

As their description says,

> The Spring Framework takes care of all the grungy, low-level details that can make JDBC such a tedious API to develop with.

The Spring Framework library is available on the [SpringSource download page](http://www.springsource.org/download).  You can download the library, and it will be packaged with all of the JARs it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache DB Utils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) is somewhat similar to DAAB. Lightweight, simple, flexible. It wraps JDBC API.

However, mapping result sets to objects is all up to you.